# How do I refresh a div class in a PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have the following `PHP` code and I'm trying to refresh a `div class` but I am new to `javascript` and am stuck

The div class I am trying to refresh is called mta
I'm looking to simply refresh that div every 3 minutes or so between 6:45 AM and 7:15 AM and again at 6:40 PM an 7:00 PM

The `mta divclass` calls the `mm-mta.js` which I have below in the body.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm a rookie here.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <style type="text/css">
    <?php include('css/main.css') ?>
   </style>
  </head>
<body>

<div class="top left">
    <div class="date small dimmed"></div>
    <div class="time"></div>
    <div class="mta xxxsmall dimmed"></div>
</div>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/ical_parser.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script src="js/rrule.js"></script>
<script src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="js/mm-mta.js?nocache=<?php echo md5(microtime()) ?>"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By 'refresh a div', do you mean refresh its content?

Comment: for what kind of reason are you including the css through php as plain text?.. Besides, what do you mean by "refresh a div"?

Comment: Yes I would be refreshing the div's content.  I have very limited experience with this so I'm not sure of the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in javascript and call it onload event like this.

```
<html>
<body="onload="myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000*60);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, where would I put this function, would it be in a separate JS file or would I put it somewhere in my PHP file?  I tried saving this out separately and testing in jsfiddle and it did not work.

Comment: add anywhere. 
like, you can add it to head.
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000*60);
}
</script>
</head>

Comment: Thanks, I'm still struggling, is there specific code to add that just refreshes the mta div?